# Как правильно подготовить последовательность данных в НС

Tags: нейронные-сети

у меня два вопроса связанных с Нейронными Сетями

**1 Вопрос**. Как предоставлять данные с привязкой например к времени? Правильно ли я сделаю в таком случае со следующим примером :

```
Время (сек.) | Сенсор №1 (кол-во машин в пробке) | Сенсор №2 (кол-во машин в пробке)

Максимальное значение для времени = 604800 (секунд в неделе)
Максимальное кол-во машин в пробке = 100
```

**2 Вопрос**. Что делать если данные например разных типов:

Вот как быть в такой ситуации когда в одной структуре встречаются такие типы :

- Время (для удобства опять же храним в секундах)
- Параметр (обычное число, замер какой нибудь температуры например)
- Булевое `TRUE` либо `FALSE`
- Изображение (Нормализованный вектор следующего вида `{0,1,0.1,0.5,0.3, ...}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нейронные Сети (дальше НС) обычно принимают на вход вещественные числа.

- Время легко преобразуется к числу секунд/миллисекунд/микросекунд/наносекунд прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`
- при работе со строками распространено два популярных подхода:

  1. завести индексированный словарь слов и заменить слова в тексте на их индексы. Обычно в таких словарях существует специальное слово - `_UNDEFINED_` для всех слов не попавших в словарь.
  2. [One Hot Encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f): когда набор предложений преобразовывается к булевой матрице размерности: число образцов (предложений или строк) x число слов.

Пример:

```
    idx     word1  word2  word3 ... wordN
      0       0     0      1    ...   0
      1       1     1      0    ...   1
      2       1     0      1    ...   0
```

- Булевое число легко представить в виде: `1` - `True`, `0` - `False`
- Изобоажение уже является числовой 3D матрицей размерности : ширина x высота x число цветовых каналов (например 3 канала для цветного RGB (Red/Green/Blue) изображения)

Часто вектора (столбцы) нормализуют - приводят к диапазону значений `[0, 1]` или `[-1, 1]` - иначе значения столбцов имеющие более высокие порядки могут получить более высокие веса и "вытеснить" другие признаки.

Comment: Так а в первом вопросе, я правильно структуру сделал для временн(о)й последовательности данных?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, думаю, да